# "No instance of overloaded function matches the specified type error" - Binary Search Tree C++

Tags: c++, templates, struct, binary-search-tree, function-templates-overloading

I'm trying to implement binary search tree in c++. Problem is that I get an error, when I try to implement functions so it can work for structs and ints

This is the haeder file for binary search tree template
bst.h

```
// Forward declaration of Node template
template <typename T>
struct Node;

template <>
struct Node<Car> {
    using NodePtr = std::shared_ptr<Node<Car>>; ///< Pointer to a tree node.
    Car value;
    NodePtr left;
    NodePtr right;

    Node(const Car& val) : value(val), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
};

template <typename T>
struct Node {
    using NodePtr = std::shared_ptr<Node<T>>; ///< Pointer to a tree node.
    T value;
    NodePtr left;
    NodePtr right;

    Node(const T& val) : value(val), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
};
/**
 * @brief Template class for a binary search tree.
 *
 * @param T The type of elements stored in the tree.
 */
template <typename T>
class BST {

    
public:
    
using ValueType = T;                   ///< The type of elements stored in the tree.
    struct Node;
    using NodePtr = std::shared_ptr<Node>; ///< Pointer to a tree node.

    

    /**
     * @brief Pointer to the root node of the BST.
     */
    NodePtr root;

    /**
     * @brief Default constructor.
     */
    BST() noexcept = default;                                ///< Default constructor.

    /**
     * @brief Copy constructor.
     *
     * @param other The BST to copy.
     */
    BST(const BST& other) = delete;                       ///< Copy constructor.

    /**
     * @brief Move constructor.
     *
     * @param other The BST to move.
     */
    BST(BST&& other) noexcept = default;                   ///< Move constructor.

    /**
     * @brief Destructor.
     */
    ~BST() = default;                                   ///< Destructor.

template <typename U>
        void inorderTraversal(const std::shared_ptr<Node<U>>& node, std::ostream& output) const {
        if (node) {
        inorderTraversal(node->left, output);
        output << node->value.make << " " << node->value.model << " " << node->value.year << " ";
        inorderTraversal(node->right, output);
        }
    }
};

// Explicit instantiation for Car type
template class BST<Car>;

// Explicit instantiation for int type
template class BST<int>;
```

This is a file with functions defined in header file:
bst.cpp

```
template <typename U>
void BST<U>::inorderTraversal(const std::shared_ptr<Node<U>>& node, std::ostream& output) const {
    if (node) {
        inorderTraversal(node->left, output);
        output << node->value.make << " " << node->value.model << " " << node->value.year << " ";
        inorderTraversal(node->right, output);
    }
}

template <>
void BST<int>::inorderTraversal(const std::shared_ptr<Node<int>>& node, std::ostream& output) const {
    if (node) {
        inorderTraversal(node->left, output);
        output << node->value << " ";
        inorderTraversal(node->right, output);
    }
}

template class BST<Car>; // Explicit instantiation for Car type
template class BST<int>; // Explicit instantiation for int type
```

A file that contains declaration of a struct that I want to implement:
struct.cpp

```
struct Car {
  std::string make;
  std::string model;
  int year;

  Car(const std::string& make, const std::string& model, int year) : make(make), model(model), year(year) {}

};
```

I've tried taking it out of a class, making private, but nothing worked.

Comment: Templates don't work this way. ***Everything*** that goes with a template must be ***fully defined*** in a header file, instead of a cpp file. See the linked question for more information.